# Cannot Connect to Nifi using localhost:8080/nifi

Tags: ubuntu, apache-nifi

Sorry there are some questions about this issue but the answers did not help me.  I have:

- ufw enabled
- a rule to allow connections to 8080 from anywhere
- ssh enabled
- status of nifi:  running, listening to bootstrap on port xxxxx, PID=yyyy

This is all on an Ubuntu vm.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recently default port of apache nifi changed from 8080 to 8443. you can change this by using docker -e flag like this:

```
docker run --name nifi -p 8080:8080 -e NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT='8080' -d apache/nifi:latest
```

Comment: mhhnull thank you very much I should have caught that!   You now have to login and I hope this helps someone else - you will have to change your username/password as sudo using this command:  $ ./bin/nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials <username> <password>

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with mapping port, by default port is 8443 in latest version.I used 1.22 and upper.
Ttry this link, when you'r nifi's configuration default. Nifi used context /nifi.
https://localhost:8443/nifi/